# Output IN_MEMORY for arcpy.analysis.Split()

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, in-memory, arcgis-notebook

I am using the arcpy module within the Jupyter Notebook to automate a sequence of ArcGIS tools. Most of the outputs I use are "in_memory", only the tool "arcpy.analysis.Split()" which I could not use a temporary storage.
Can anyone help me achieve this? I don't want to use gdb Scratch.

I am using the jupyter notebook from the Arcgis PRO installation

Python version = 3.6.9
Arcgis PRO version = 2.5

[image: slice of code]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions should include the code *as text, in the body of the Question*, since an image of code requires anyone who would want to reproduce your code to type it over. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Try `memory` instead of `in_memory`?